# Good web hosting for ASP.NET MVC 1.0 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-hosting

I'm looking for hosting for an ASP.NET MVC 1.0 app.  I've narrowed down with research to either asphostportal, asphostcentral, godaddy, or 1&1.  I've ruled out crystaltech and softsyshosting due to price with better plans.

Will be running a small e-commerce site written with ASP.NET MVC 1.0 and want to be sure it will work, as well as looking for cheapest price with best value in regards to disk space/bandwidth.  And bandwidth is basically how much data can be sent from your site per month right?  Any opinions appreciated as I'm finding this tough to narrow down.  I know you can bin deploy MVC but heard full trust mode is required as well as some routing rules in IIS. 1&1 says they can't enable full trust.

This is what I was looking at:

```
name            data(disk space/bandwidth)  price               MVCenabled
crystal tech    500MB/50GB                   7.95 + 7.95 setup
                2000MB/200GB                16.95
softsyshosting  500MB/5GB                    3.50 + 12/year domain
                1000MB/10GB                  5.84
                3000MB/30GB                 13.33
asphostportal   5GB/50GB                     5.75 + 8.99/year          yes
                10GB/100GB                  10.25
asphostcentral  2GB/15GB                     4.99                      yes
                3GB/30GB                     7.99/month domain free
                5GB/40GB                    11.99
godaddy         10GB/300GB                  10.69 + 4.74/month
                150GB/1500GB                 6.99/month
1&1             10GB/unlimited               3.99 + free domain
                150GB/unlimited              6.99
```

1&1 seems to be best value *if* MVC app will work.  I'm a bit confused on bandwidth being unlimited.  May seem like a good thing, but what if one website on the server is a resource hog because of this?

Comment: There is no such thing as unlimited bandwidth - it is just a marketing term.  Any provider will drop or migrate you (for a fee) if you are using disproportionate resources.

Comment: I don't think this is really an appropriate question for SO.  But, for what it's worth please avoid 1&1 like the plague - they are awful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up going with GoDaddy for now.  Got a good deal.  $1.99 domain with deluxe package.  Went with deluxe as found 20% off promo code with a google search.  Paid $65 total.  Will be able to jump to a dedicated server for a reasonable price as well if needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for "Shared Hosting"?  If so, I can tell you from experience that running a web site from shared hosting can become a nightmare because you only have so much control over the setup.

I went with a Virtual Private Server (VPS), which gives you complete control over a virtual server... (remote desktop, admin rights, etc).  I ended up going with 1&1 for a Windows VPS that runs about $30 a month, and I have been very happy with it (I have multiple MVC sites running on it).

If this is going to be a serious web site, I would consider a VPS over shared hosting.  Hope this helps!

Comment: yes this is all shared hosting.  I don't expect much traffic first few months with this site.

Answer (score 0):

Bin deploying the ASP.NET MVC [does not require full trust](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx). My host ([LiquidSix](http://www.liquidsix.com/)) runs its shared hosting options with a Medium trust setup, and I've bin deployed the both System.Web.Mvc.dll and Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll to the site with no major issues.

> Also, ASP.NET MVC runs in Medium Trust, so it should work with most hosting providers’ Medium Trust policies. It’s always possible that a hosting provider customizes their Medium Trust policy to be draconian.

The only downside with them at the moment is they are still running on IIS6, and I've not asked them/tried to set up a wild card mapping to the ASP.NET handler - so [my site](http://www.doodle.co.uk/) requires the [standard work around](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) of controllers having a .aspx extension.

> One nice benefit of using the .aspx extension instead of .mvc is that you don’t have to worry about mapping the .aspx extension. It should already be mapped assuming you have ASP.NET installed properly on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use asphostportal. They've been spamming the StackExchange network like crazy. Just do a google search for "asphostportal stackexchange" and you'll see tons of posts by [users](https://stackoverflow.com/users/455768/robert-springfield) who link to their site in every answer (even when it's completely irrelevant and the question poster isn't asking for web hosting recommendations).

I'd be weary of doing business with any company that advertises their services by spamming online communities, regardless of how good their prices are. It's just unprofessional and not to mention scummy.